# Flexbox justify-content: space-between with padding as the space rather than margin

Tags: css

I have the following design currently:
[image: Current state of design]

```js
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.nav-item').each(function(index) {
  totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
});
$('.nav-item').css('padding-left', ($('.navbar-nav').width() - totalWidth) / 10);
$('.nav-item').css('padding-right', ($('.navbar-nav').width() - totalWidth) / 10);
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(188 174 159);
  font-family: source-serif-pro, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 0.7vw;
  padding-top: 0.7vw;
  max-height: 9vh;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 7.5vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 2vw;
  background-color: #e4dbd1 !important;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(9vh - 3px);
}

.nav-link {
  color: #731d2c !important;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-link.active {
  color: #94253d !important;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #e4dbd1 !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-item {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="timeline.html">Timeline</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="essays.html">Short Essays</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="bibliography.html">Bibliography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The lighter colour is what the intended hover effect will be.

At the moment I am using:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

in order to create the spacing between the elements. This gives me even spacing which is ideal, however the lighter colour does not cover this areas as it is done via a margin.

I am wondering if this is possible to achieve via padding. I tried width 20% since there are 5 elements and 5x20%=100%, however it was odd having a 3 letter word like "Map" take up as much space as "Short Essays" which is much longer.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be ideal.

**UPDATE:**
I was able to achieve a solution using Javascript/Jquery as follows:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.nav-item').each(function(index) {
    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);            
});
$('.nav-item').css('padding-left', ($('.navbar-nav').width() - totalWidth)/10);
$('.nav-item').css('padding-right', ($('.navbar-nav').width() - totalWidth)/10);
```

Comment: Please post a [example].

Comment: @Kameron added, although you will need to view in full screen of expanded snippet.

Comment: @evilgenious448 that lighter will cover to the end of the bar or only nav items?

Comment: how about you set background color to the whole `.navbar-nav` instead of indivudual `.nav-item`?

Comment: @AndrewYmaz Because if you read my question, you will notice that this is a hover effect that should come up for each item when it is hovered. I am just showing them all at the same time to show the issue I am having with the paddings/margins. The point is not just to have it all in one background color.

Comment: @NickVu I am thinking to add it to the logo as well, so all of the nav bar, not just nav items.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for `nav-item`

*Note that I'm using `min-width: 992px` because [Bootstrap's tablet breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/) is 992px*

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-item {
    font-size: 25px;
    flex: 0 1 20%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  /*For hovering testing*/
  .nav-item:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(188 174 159);
  font-family: source-serif-pro, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 0.7vw;
  padding-top: 0.7vw;
  max-height: 9vh;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 7.5vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 2vw;
  background-color: #e4dbd1 !important;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(9vh - 3px);
}

.nav-link {
  color: #731d2c !important;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-link.active {
  color: #94253d !important;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #e4dbd1 !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-item {
    font-size: 25px;
    flex: 0 1 20%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  /*For hovering testing*/
  .nav-item:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="timeline.html">Timeline</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="essays.html">Short Essays</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="bibliography.html">Bibliography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As for your case, you don't want to have them equally due to content length. I'd suggest that you should modify [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) in `flex`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-item {
    font-size: 25px;
    flex: 2 1 auto; /*set flex-grow to 2 and flex-basis to auto*/
    justify-content: center;
  }
  /*For hovering testing*/
  .nav-item:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

*One side note is that on the bigger screen with enough space, the width size is distributed equally, but on the smaller screen, you will see that the width size will be distributed according to content length*

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(188 174 159);
  font-family: source-serif-pro, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 0.7vw;
  padding-top: 0.7vw;
  max-height: 9vh;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 7.5vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 2vw;
  background-color: #e4dbd1 !important;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(9vh - 3px);
}

.nav-link {
  color: #731d2c !important;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav-link.active {
  color: #94253d !important;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #e4dbd1 !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-item {
    font-size: 25px;
    flex: 2 1 auto;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  /*For hovering testing*/
  .nav-item:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="timeline.html">Timeline</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="essays.html">Short Essays</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="bibliography.html">Bibliography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not quite achieve what I want. This is the same as setting the width of each item to 20%. The reason why I am not a fan of this, is because I don't believe a 3 letter word like "Map" should have as much space allocated to it as "Short Essays".

Comment: I updated my answer with `flex: 2 1 auto;`, you can check it out with some comments, @evilgenious448